# Use SQL 2012 FORMAT function with LINQ to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to add the built in SQL 2012 FORMAT function to a static function class to use with LINQ to Entity Framework.
I followed [this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlFunctions.cs) source code to mimic adding a built in SQL function.

```
public static class ExtendSqlFunctions
{    
    [DbFunction("SqlServer", "FORMAT")]
    public static string Format(Int64? arg, string formatType, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }    
}
```

> **ERROR:**   The specified method 'System.String Format(System.Nullable`1[System.Int64], System.String, System.String)'
>   on the type 'ExtendSqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to
>   Entities store expression.

**UPDATE**
I was able to get a working version by adding "FORMAT" to the SSDL of the Entity Framework model.
So it looks like Microsoft does not support "DbFunction SqlServer" outside of their internal libraries.
Not sure about this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738614(v=vs.100).aspx
If someone knows how to add a built in SQL function without editing the SSDL then please let me know.

**UPDATE**
I have added this as an issue on CodePlex
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2586
and "rjperes" added it as a discussion on CodePlex.
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/572518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Code First (not clear from your question), besides applying the DbFunction attribute, you also need to register the function on the model, in the OnModelCreating method. The name and namespace you set in the DbFunction attribute must match the call to EdmFunction.Create. See a full example here: [Registering SQL Server Built-in Functions to Entity Framework Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/registering-sql-server-built-in-functions-to-entity-framework-code-first)

Answer (score 2):

[EntityFramework.Functions](https://github.com/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions) library provides a nice way to declare various database functions and reference them in C# code. FORMAT function can be declared as:

```
public static class DatabaseFunctions
{
    [Function(FunctionType.BuiltInFunction, "FORMAT")]
    public static string Format(decimal value, string format) => Function.CallNotSupported<string>();
}
```

It then should be included in DB context's OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //  ...
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionConvention(typeof(DatabaseFunctions)));
}
```

and after that it can be used like

```
context.Items.Select(i => DatabaseFunctions.Format(i.Value, "0.00"));
```